# Condition for Insert data into database table

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

New to Js and stuck here. What should I put into my if statement to insert data into database table? Because right now I do get intended error message when I submit a wrong value but it still inserts it to database. Appreciate the help!
Here is my index.js

```
    var manageMemberTable;
    $("#addMemberModalBtn").on('click', function() {
        // reset the form 
        $("#createMemberForm")[0].reset();
        // remove the error 
        $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');
        $(".text-danger").remove();
        // empty the message div
        $(".messages").html("");

        // submit form
        $("#createMemberForm").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {

            $(".text-danger").remove();

            var form = $(this);

            // validation
            var firstname = $("#firstname").val();
            var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
```

this is what I'm checking

```
    if (firstname == "") {
                $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $("#firstname").after('<p class="text-danger">The firstname field is required</p>');
            }
            else {

            if (firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/) === null){
                $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $("#firstname").after('<p class="text-danger">Firstname invalid</p>');
            }
            else {
                $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
            }   
            }           


                //lastname validation

                if (lastname == "") {
                    $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#lastname").after('<p class="text-danger">The lastname field is required</p>');
                }
                else {

                if (lastname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/) === null){
                    $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    $("#lastname").after('<p class="text-danger">lastname is invalid</p>');
                }
                else {
                    $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
                }
                }
```

And this is the i statement

```
if( // Something that checks the submitted data meets requirements) {
                //submit the form to server
                $.ajax({
                    url : form.attr('action'),
                    type : form.attr('method'),
                    data : form.serialize(),
                    dataType : 'json',
```

Comment: one way to handle this would be to wrap your validation in a function and return true or false from that function, and you can then use that returned value as your condition for whether or not to submit the form.

Comment: I see what you mean. Trying that out thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be one approach.

`firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)` returns `true` if the string matches the regular expression

```js
if ((firstname != "") && (firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) &&
    (lastname != "") && (lastname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/))) {
    $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');    
    // code to send data to database
}
else {
    if(firstname === ""){
        $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $("#firstname").after('<p class="text-danger">The firstname field is required</p>');
    }
    if (!firstname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)){
        $("#firstname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $("#firstname").after('<p class="text-danger">firstname is invalid</p>');
    }
    if(lastname === ""){
        $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $("#lastname").after('<p class="text-danger">The lastname field is required</p>');
    }
    if (!lastname.match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)){
        $("#lastname").closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $("#lastname").after('<p class="text-danger">lastname is invalid</p>');
    }  
}
```

Comment: This actually solved my issue! Now I just have to deal with the success message not showing on my modal ✌ Thanks!